# A software for calculations in free Lie algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, free-lie-algebra

I am interested to expand the symmetrised tensor products of several elements of the Philip Hall basis of a free Lie algebra in tensor form. For example, if the algebra has two generators $x$ and $y$, then we have $\ell_1=x$, $\ell_2=y$, $\ell_3=[x,y]$, and so on. It is easy to calculate by hand that
$$
(\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_2)=\frac{1}{3}(x\otimes y\otimes y+y\otimes x\otimes y+y\otimes x\otimes x),
$$
but the calculation of,say, $(\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_5)$ is more boring. Do there exist a software which may do such calculations?

Comment: Note, Magma has a command FreeLieAlgebra but, the last time I checked, this does not -- and is not meant to -- produce a Lie algebra. This is an important non-example!

Comment: GAP may be useful here, but I've never used it's Lie algebra features https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap64.html

Comment: I tried GAP. It successfully created free Lie algebra $L$ with two generators but failed to create its universal enveloping algebra.

Comment: I found that the web page https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ does calculations I require.